# Variadic templates with exactly n parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to make a variadic template with exactly N arguments, where N is also a template parameter. For example,

```
template <int N, typename T[N]>
void function(T t[N]) {
    // do stuff with t[0] through t[N-1]
}
```

(I realize the above is not valid syntax)

I know that one way to achieve this is to use a `static_assert` on `sizeof...(ArgsT)` where `ArgsT` is a variadic template definition (i.e. `template <typename ...ArgsT>`).

I am just wondering if there is a better way, not necessarily involving `static_assert`.

Comment: static_assert is already a nice failing of compilation (stick to it)

Comment: In summary, you want a compile time error when the pack size does not equal the int parameter ? `static_assert` is meant for this, why wouldn't it be the best way ?

Comment: You may also use SFINAE with `std::enable_if`. But I'm not sure it is better.

Comment: @Jarod42: The difference is whether you want the overloads to *exist*. Unless it's important not to pollute the overload set, a static assertion may produce easier diagnostics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::enable_if` instead of `static_assert`:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename ...Args>
auto function(Args&&... args)
    -> typename std::enable_if<N == sizeof...(Args), void>::type
{
    ...
}
```

**Update:** It's also possible to use it in constructors, where `N` is a template argument of the class.

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct foobar
{
    template <typename ...Args, typename = typename std::enable_if<N == sizeof...(Args), void>::type>
    foobar(Args&&... args) { ... }
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this for a constructor?

Comment: @par how exactly do you plan to pass in `N`?

Comment: template <std::size_t N> class A { /* STUFF */ };

Comment: As a summary for other people reading this: it should be noted that ```static_assert``` is probably the more semantically meaningful way to achieve the above, but this is a very clever way to accomplish what was asked.