# Variadic arguments (with a pack size of N) and a default argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Let `N` be a template parameter of type `std::size_t`. I would like to be able to call the constructor for my class in two ways:

```
A a(x1, x2, x3, ..., xN)
```

and

```
A a(x1, x2, x3, ..., xN, xN1)
```

where the `xi` variables are all of the same type. My first thought was to do:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct A
{
     template <typename ...Args, typename = typename std::enable_if<N == sizeof...(Args), void>::type>
     A(Args ...args) {
         f(args...); // where f is some function
     }

     template <typename ...Args, typename = typename std::enable_if<N+1 == sizeof...(Args), void>::type>
     A(Args ...args) {
         // run f on the first N arguments
         // run g on the last argument (selection is done using templates, I just did not want to write the code)
     }
};
```

This technique is explained at: [Variadic templates with exactly n parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458498/variadic-templates-with-exactly-n-parameters).
Of course, the problem with this is that you cannot overload the constructor this way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just SFINAE it differently:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct A
{
     template <typename ...Args, 
               typename std::enable_if<N == sizeof...(Args), int>::type = 0>
     A(Args ...args) {
     }

     template <typename ...Args, 
               typename std::enable_if<N+1 == sizeof...(Args), int>::type = 0>
     A(Args ...args) {
     }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bea08ef29eebbbd3).

Comment: Could you explain the difference?

Comment: @0x499602D2 The one in the OP redefines the same function template (with a different default argument). Making the `enable_if` part of the signature makes these two distinct function templates.

Comment: So should the former ever be used for SFINAE?

Comment: Both are fine in general. The first just can't be used if the overloads would otherwise have the exact same signature.